# Android app that not shown in Setting > Battery

Tags: android

is this possible an App uses very much battery and not shown in Setting > Battery in the Android?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware/software tech support.

Comment: No, as this might not be editable by any app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of Android, an application can mask itself under a few headings under battery based on the features they use. Two of these are Mediaserver (apps like "Rayman Fiesta Run") and Voice Calls (apps like "Skype"). System applications can be obfuscated under "Android System" (apps like "ANT HAL Service"). How the placement of these apps is achieved, I do not know. Look for one of those "headings" and see if the app in question would make sense to be there.